# When submitting/creating a custom timer job in SharePoint, how is the job's ID set?

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I have a number of custom jobs that my program adds to my SharePoint environment. I noticed that there is no option to give the job a particular ID/GUID in [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.spjobdefinition.aspx). So my question is: How is new job's GUID/ID assigned when created and submitted?

I'm aware that I can access and modify that member of the SPJobDefinition, but I'm curious how it's set otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

When the instance of [job definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.aspx) is created it [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.id.aspx) property is initialized via base [SPPersistedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.aspx) constructor to `Guid.NewGuid()` :

```
protected SPPersistedObject(string name, SPPersistedObject parent)
  : this(name, parent, Guid.NewGuid())
{
}
```